# Why does onClick event only working once in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html and javaScript. The onclick showHiddenDiv event only work for the first `<li>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
           <h3 class="assignments"><a href="#users" onclick="showHiddenDiv('div-1')">
           Assignment 1</a></h3>
           <p class="date">Tuesday Sep 9</p>
           <div id="div-1" style="display:none">Completed</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3 class="assignments"><a href="#users" onclick="showHiddenDiv('div-2')">
             Assignment 2 </a></h3>
             <p class="date">Thursday Sep 11</p>
             <div id="id-2" style="display:none">Completed. 
             The web page can be found at this link.</a></div>
         </li>
     </ul>

<script>
function showHiddenDiv(id) {
  "use strict";
   var obj = document.getElementById(id);
   if (obj.style.display === "none") {
      obj.style.display = 'block';
   } else if (obj.style.display === "block") {
      obj.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I call the javaScript function with onclick to work multiple times in html?

Comment: Because the second div has `id-2` but you expect it to be `div-2`

Comment: Where is your `div-2`? :)

Comment: ooops!! typo mistake. -_- Problem solved! Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <div id="div-1" style="display:none">Completed</div>
            ^^^^---- spot the difference
     <div id="id-2" style="display:none">Completed. 
              ^^^^--- spot the difference
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have flagged the question as off-topic due to a typo?

Comment: Typo mistake :3. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div id="id-2"` to `<div id="div-2"`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have flagged the question as off-topic due to a typo?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your html also id-2 should be div-2.

```
<p class="date">Thursday Sep 11</p>
         <div id="div-2" style="display:none">Completed. 
         <a>The web page can be found at this link.</a></div>
```

You need opening a tag.

Comment: True, but that doesn't answer the question nor fix the problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with letting him know

Comment: Then it should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: How can i post code in a comment? Let me know...

Comment: You surround it with backticks. Read the help. `<p class="date">Thursday Sep 11</p>`